# In C, how should I cut a text file between a char and another?

Tags: c, file, gcc, cygwin, text-files

I try to code a program cutting a text file between a character and another. To illustrate, `example.txt` that I want to cut includes numbers and some characters such as `'[[['` and `]]]` (they may chance as type and count of charters). These characters mark the start or end of the cutting process.

This process looks like it is simple; however it may be tiring and carrying risk which is high possibility of making a mistake. Anyway while I am writing the question, I solve a lot of problems about my problem except saving to another text file. `[[[`'s count is uncertain: that is to say, I don't know how many files I have to create. I am open to new thoughts and ideas, no matter which programming language it is.

## **Input file example and its outputs:**

**example.txt**

> 005076,-0.00008389,0.00039446,-0.00007079,0.00024138,0.00059449,-0.000
>   24860,**[[[**
>   0.00032513,0.00000142,0.00001302,0.00000965,0.00005201,0.00001  395,-0.00003729,-0.00001774,-0.00002842,0.00000745,0.00143565,-0.00014
>   975,0.00166676,0.00086413,-0.00071107,-0.00081336,-0.10930688,0.062458
>   9,-0.00000142,0.00001301,0.00000965,-0.00005203,-0.00001394,-0.0000373
>   0,0.00001775,0.00002840,0.00000747,0.00143637,0.00015079,0.00166945
>   **]]]**
>    0.00086406,0.00071132,-0.00081439,0.10930956,-0.06242029,-0.21353303,0  00003668,-0.00000001,0.00088168,-0.03589109,-0.00000584,0.00366844,0.0
>   **[[[** 0.3708,-0.00000623,-0.00000093,-0.00001597,-0.00010373,-0.00001235,-
>    0.00008982,0.00008547,0.00000138,0.00001692,-0.00005915,0.00000005,0.0   090,0.00000182,-0.00000396,-0.00000575,0.00000367,0.00000364,-0.000012
>   73,0.00004112,-0.00000056,0.00007256,0.00001237,-0.00000176 **]]]**

**cut1.txt**

> 0.00032513,0.00000142,0.00001302,0.00000965,0.00005201,0.00001  395,-0.00003729,-0.00001774,-0.00002842,0.00000745,0.00143565,-0.00014
>   975,0.00166676,0.00086413,-0.00071107,-0.00081336,-0.10930688,0.062458
>   9,-0.00000142,0.00001301,0.00000965,-0.00005203,-0.00001394,-0.0000373
>   0,0.00001775,0.00002840,0.00000747,0.00143637,0.00015079,0.00166945

**cut2.txt**

> 0.3708,-0.00000623,-0.00000093,-0.00001597,-0.00010373,-0.00001235,-
>    0.00008982,0.00008547,0.00000138,0.00001692,-0.00005915,0.00000005,0.0   090,0.00000182,-0.00000396,-0.00000575,0.00000367,0.00000364,-0.000012
>   73,0.00004112,-0.00000056,0.00007256,0.00001237,-0.00000176

## **Compiler system information:**

```
$ cygcheck --version
cygcheck (cygwin) 2.0.4
System Checker for Cygwin
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2015 Red Hat, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

## Compile information

> $ gcc -o cutt cutt.c
>
> $ ./cutt
>
> 0.00032513,0.00000142,0.00001302,0.00000965,0.00005201,0.00001 395,-0.00003729,-0.00001774,-0.00002842,0.00000745,0.00143565,-0.00014
>   975,0.00166676,0.00086413,-0.00071107,-0.00081336,-0.10930688,0.062458
>   9,-0.00000142,0.00001301,0.00000965,-0.00005203,-0.00001394,-0.0000373
>   0,0.00001775,0.00002840,0.00000747,0.00143637,0.00015079,0.00166945
>   **]][** 0.3708,-0.00000623,-0.00000093,-0.00001597,-0.00010373,-0.00001235,- 0.00008982,0.00008547,0.00000138,0.00001692,-0.00005915,0.00000005,0.0 090,0.00000182,-0.00000396,-0.00000575,0.00000367,0.00000364,-0.000012
>   73,0.00004112,-0.00000056,0.00007256,0.00001237,-0.00000176

If so, how many `[[[` and `]]]` v `cutN.txt` files. needed.

## **Cutt's code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024

int testp=0, r=0;
char cx[MAX_LEN],cz[MAX_LEN];
void Cutt(char[],char[],int);

main()
{
    FILE *fpR, *fpW;
    char ch[MAX_LEN],sEArch4[3];
    int chc,i=0,cxc;
    sEArch4[1]=0x5b;sEArch4[2]=0x5b;sEArch4[3]=0x5b;

    fpR = fopen("example.txt","r");
    if (fpR==NULL) { 
        printf("Could not open example.txt !\n"); 
        return 1;
    }

    fpW = fopen("cut1.txt","w");
    if (fpW==NULL) { 
        printf("Could not open cut1.txt!\n"); 
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(ch,MAX_LEN,fpR)) {
        //printf("%s",ch);
        chc = strlen(ch);
        for(i=0;i<chc;i++)
            //printf("%s %d %d",ch,i,chc);
            Cutt(ch,sEArch4,i);
    }
    //printf("%s",cx);
    cxc = strlen(cx);
    for(i=1;i<cxc-2;i++)
        cz[i-1] = cx[i];
    printf("%s",cz);
//Jump; 
    return 0;
}
void Cutt(char ch[],char sEArch4[],int i)
{
    int j,k=0;
    for (j=i ; j<i+strlen(sEArch4) ; j++ ) {
        if(ch[j]!=sEArch4[k]){
            if ( ch [j] == 0x5b && ch [j-1] == 0x5b && ch [j-2] == 0x5b ) {
                testp = 1;
            }
            if ( ch [j] == 0x5d && ch [j-1] == 0x5d && ch [j-2] == 0x5d ) {
                testp = 2;
            }   
            if(testp==1) {  
                cx[r] = ch[j];
                r++;
                return;
            }
            //printf("testp:%d \nch:%s\n",testp,x);
            if(testp==2)
                return;
            //goto Jump;
            else
                return; 
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
For single cut, it runs free of problems. for more than one cut, there is  `]][` chars. Look at compile information. I think it will use for cut.

Comment: Each time you come across the sequence `[[[`, you need to start copying the input text to a new file _'cutN.txt'_ where the _N_ is the number of times you've seen the `[[[`. When you come across `]]]`, you stop writing to the current output file. The `[[[` and `]]]` should not be echoed at all. Any material not between `[[[` and `]]]` should be printed to standard output. If you're writing to a file when you encounter EOF on the input, you should report an error. So, if the `example.txt` file was concatenated with itself, there should be 4 output files: `cut1.txt` through `cut4.txt`.  Correct?

Comment: Writing `if ( ch [j] == 0x5b && ch [j-1] == 0x5b && ch [j-2] == 0x5b ) {` is diabolical.  Use `'['` or `#define LSQ '['` and use `LSQ` or something.  Don't use `0x5B`.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I need just between [[[ and ]]] values.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches to solving the problem.  One is reading line-by-line, as you're doing, and the other is character-by-character.  There are some advantages to the character-by-character approach, but a primary advantage is that if you deal with things a character at a time, you don't have to fret about special cases such as a single line containing:

```
0.345[[[0.456]]]0.001[[[0.002]]]0.999[[[
```

If you scan line at a time, you have to deal with such difficult data rather carefully.  It isn't entirely clear from copying the data in the question whether it is all on one line anyway.  Also, the code has to deal accurately with `[[` or `[` followed by something other than `[`, and similarly with `]]` or `]` followed by something other than `]`.

You don't seem to have code that opens a different file each time you recognize the `[[[` sequence; you also don't clearly have code that closes the auxilliary file.  Presumably, if the last character before the `]]]` sequence is not a newline, the code should output a newline so that the text file does in fact end with a newline.

A general purpose command would have arguments to specify the open sequence, the close sequence, the prefix to the output file names, possibly the suffix, and would read the files specified on the command line, or default to standard input if no files were specified.  For the purposes of this exercise, we'll leave everything hardwired, but that isn't the way it should be done in the long term.

Here's what I'd do.  Be cautious about submitting it as an answer — it does stuff that you might not have thought of doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int filenum = 0;
static const char s_mark[] = "[[[";
static const char e_mark[] = "]]]";
static const char f_prefix[] = "cut";
static const char f_suffix[] = ".txt";
static const char datafile[] = "example.txt";

static FILE *open_file(void)
{
    char filename[32];
    snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s%d%s", f_prefix, ++filenum, f_suffix);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create file %s for writing\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

static void dump_to_file(FILE *ifp)
{
    FILE *ofp = open_file();
    int ch;
    char last = '\0';
    int e_mark_idx = 0;

    while ((ch = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == e_mark[e_mark_idx])
        {
            e_mark_idx++;
            if (e_mark[e_mark_idx] == '\0')
            {
                /* All done */
                if (last != '\n')
                    putc('\n', ofp);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e_mark_idx > 0)
                fprintf(ofp, "%.*s", e_mark_idx, e_mark);
            e_mark_idx = 0;
            putc(ch, ofp);
            last = ch;
        }
    }

    fclose(ofp);
}

int main(void)
{
    int s_mark_idx = 0;
    int ch;
    FILE *ifp = fopen(datafile, "r");

    if (ifp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == s_mark[s_mark_idx])
        {
            s_mark_idx++;
            if (s_mark[s_mark_idx] == '\0')
            {
                /* Found start marker - dup following text to file */
                dump_to_file(ifp);
                s_mark_idx = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (s_mark_idx > 0)
                printf("%.*s", s_mark_idx, s_mark);
            s_mark_idx = 0;
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

Given this sample input file:

```
005076,-0.00008389,0.00039446,-0.00007079,0.00024138,0.00059449,-0.000 24860,[[[ 0.00032513,0.00000142,0.00001302,0.00000965,0.00005201,0.00001 395,-0.00003729,-0.00001774,-0.00002842,0.00000745,0.00143565,-0.00014 975,0.00166676,0.00086413,-0.00071107,-0.00081336,-0.10930688,0.062458 9,-0.00000142,0.00001301,0.00000965,-0.00005203,-0.00001394,-0.0000373 0,0.00001775,0.00002840,0.00000747,0.00143637,0.00015079,0.00166945 ]]] 0.00086406,0.00071132,-0.00081439,0.10930956,-0.06242029,-0.21353303,0 00003668,-0.00000001,0.00088168,-0.03589109,-0.00000584,0.00366844,0.0 [[[ 0.3708,-0.00000623,-0.00000093,-0.00001597,-0.00010373,-0.00001235,- 0.00008982,0.00008547,0.00000138,0.00001692,-0.00005915,0.00000005,0.0 090,0.00000182,-0.00000396,-0.00000575,0.00000367,0.00000364,-0.000012 73,0.00004112,-0.00000056,0.00007256,0.00001237,-0.00000176 ]]]
0.345[[[0.456]]]0.001[[[0.002]]]0.999[[[
0.2333]]]
[[0.234[234.567]]]0.000[[[0.123]0.234]]0.345]]]
```

It generates standard output:

```
005076,-0.00008389,0.00039446,-0.00007079,0.00024138,0.00059449,-0.000 24860, 0.00086406,0.00071132,-0.00081439,0.10930956,-0.06242029,-0.21353303,0 00003668,-0.00000001,0.00088168,-0.03589109,-0.00000584,0.00366844,0.0 
0.3450.0010.999
[[0.234[234.567]]]0.000
```

And files `cut1.txt` to `cut6.txt`:

```
cut1.txt: 0.00032513,0.00000142,0.00001302,0.00000965,0.00005201,0.00001 395,-0.00003729,-0.00001774,-0.00002842,0.00000745,0.00143565,-0.00014 975,0.00166676,0.00086413,-0.00071107,-0.00081336,-0.10930688,0.062458 9,-0.00000142,0.00001301,0.00000965,-0.00005203,-0.00001394,-0.0000373 0,0.00001775,0.00002840,0.00000747,0.00143637,0.00015079,0.00166945 
cut2.txt: 0.3708,-0.00000623,-0.00000093,-0.00001597,-0.00010373,-0.00001235,- 0.00008982,0.00008547,0.00000138,0.00001692,-0.00005915,0.00000005,0.0 090,0.00000182,-0.00000396,-0.00000575,0.00000367,0.00000364,-0.000012 73,0.00004112,-0.00000056,0.00007256,0.00001237,-0.00000176 
cut3.txt:0.456
cut4.txt:0.002
cut5.txt:
cut5.txt:0.2333
cut6.txt:0.123]0.234]]0.345
```